# locate [file] but go to directory, it's not there

Tags: permissions, apache2, files, php, locate

I am root.
I have PHP webpage on Apache 2 server putting .stl files in /var/www/upload using move_uploaded_file( 'from', 'to' )

- When I use locate, I see the file is in /var/www/upload
- When I cd to the directory and ls, or ls -al, no files are present
- This is probably something to do with permissions, right?

Terminal dump:

```
    root@debian:/var/www/upload# ls -al
    total 8
    drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Sep 21 17:45 .
    drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Sep 21 17:45 ..
    root@debian:/var/www/upload# locate Octocat
    /home/user/Desktop/Octocat-v1.stl
    /var/www/upload/Octocat-v1.stl
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Locate isn't realtime, it's data might have expired.

Comment: @Mace I have learned I can use `updatedb` to refresh locate's data. I will go find out what cron is now.. Thank you.

Comment: @muru it likely is. It would seem my call to move_uploaded_file(.., ..) is failing, I shall investigate my php code. Thank you both.

Comment: @mynameisnafe yes, run `sudo updatedb`. Also check the error logs of apache, and also the return values of the PHP function.

Comment: @mynameisnafe Sure thing. The command updatedb does it and is typically being run periodically via crontab. Once a day in Ubuntu, by default

Comment: Ah ye olde `tail -10 apache.log` or something. I have spent too long away from linuxland.